# Reformatting half the columns of an SQL table into a transpose like transformation and retaining the other half as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an sql table in the following format:

```
col1    col2    col3    2000    2001    2002    2003
a        b      c       1       2       3       4
d        e      f       5       6       7       8
g        h      i       9       2       6       8
j        k      l       5       5       7       3
```

I need the output in the following format:

```
col1    col2    col3    year    amount
a       b       c       2000    1
a       b       c       2001    2
a       b       c       2002    3
a       b       c       2003    4
d       e       f       2000    5
d       e       f       2001    6
d       e       f       2002    7
d       e       f       2003    8
g       h       i       2000    9
g       h       i       2001    2
g       h       i       2002    6
g       h       i       2003    8
j       k       l       2000    5
j       k       l       2001    5
j       k       l       2002    7
j       k       l       2003    3
```

I tried various types of joins and cross-joins. They don't seem to work.

Comment: *"I tried various types of joins and cross-joins. They don't seem to work."* and what were those attempts? Why didn't they work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot#unpivot-example) operation...

```sql
-- Data setup...
create table dbo.Example (
  col1 char(1),
  col2 char(1),
  col3 char(1),
  [2000] int,
  [2001] int,
  [2002] int,
  [2003] int
);
insert dbo.Example (col1, col2, col3, [2000], [2001], [2002], [2003])
values
  ('a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3, 4),
  ('d', 'e', 'f', 5, 6, 7, 8),
  ('g', 'h', 'i', 9, 2, 6, 8),
  ('j', 'k', 'l', 5, 5, 7, 3);

-- Unpivot query...
select
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  year,
  amount
from dbo.Example raw
unpivot (amount for year in ([2000], [2001], [2002], [2003])) u;
```

Which yields the result...

| col1 | col2 | col3 | year | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | 2000 | 1 |
| a | b | c | 2001 | 2 |
| a | b | c | 2002 | 3 |
| a | b | c | 2003 | 4 |
| d | e | f | 2000 | 5 |
| d | e | f | 2001 | 6 |
| d | e | f | 2002 | 7 |
| d | e | f | 2003 | 8 |
| g | h | i | 2000 | 9 |
| g | h | i | 2001 | 2 |
| g | h | i | 2002 | 6 |
| g | h | i | 2003 | 8 |
| j | k | l | 2000 | 5 |
| j | k | l | 2001 | 5 |
| j | k | l | 2002 | 7 |
| j | k | l | 2003 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of the official `UNPIVOT` operator, it's often easier to just use `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`.**

This is especially useful when you have other joins, or if you want multiple un-pivoted columns.

```sql
select
  t.col1,
  t.col2,
  t.col3,
  v.year,
  v.amount
from YourTable t
cross apply (values
    ([2000], 2000),
    ([2001], 2001),
    ([2002], 2002),
    ([2003], 2003)
) v(amount, year);
```